# What's an eloquent way of linking a model variable to the DOM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller, I have this:

```
@todones = Todo.where(done:true,user:current_user.email).order('updated_at DESC')
```

In a corresponding view, I have `<h3 id="done" class="semi_title"> <%= @todones.size %> tasks done </h3>`

And of course, this only gets rendered when the page loads, meaning it doesn't really dynamically count for you.

What I could do is load in the number at the beginning, and add or subtract to that count using Javascript when elements are added or deleted.

I was wondering if there was a more Rails way to approach this though.

Comment: The only way to do this, as i know is you should do it through ajax.

Comment: Making an AJAX call every time an element is added or deleted you mean?

Comment: Yes, this is a grate way to deal with page dynamically.